# Looking for some fields in TravelItineraryReadRS

Tags: xml, sabre

I am looking for some fields in TravelItineraryReadRS XML
1. Title of a person
2. Initial of a person
3. PAXAge of a person
4. AgeFactor of a person

They were extracted from clear text respnose. But I can not find corresponding element in xsd. http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/pnrservices/TravelItineraryReadRS3.5.0.xsd

Thanks for your help.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

It is my understanding that there are no specific tags for those fields. As per the format in which you enter the name information in Sabre host system, both the initial and the title would be included on the first name field should you include them on your request.

This is how you enter them in Sabre terminal:

```
-TEST/SWS J MR
```

This is how it looks on the TravelItineraryReadRS:

```
<PersonName WithInfant="false" NameNumber="01.01" PassengerType="ADT" RPH="1">
    <GivenName>SWS J MR</GivenName>
    <Surname>TEST</Surname>
</PersonName>
```

The age will depend on the passenger type, you can check more information using Format Finder (pages ptcov003 and ptcov004), take the child for example, according to Format Finder:

```
Accompanied child - CNN (NN indicates the age). Example: C10
```

This is how it looks on TravelItineraryReadRS:

```
<PersonName WithInfant="false" NameNumber="02.01" PassengerType="C10" RPH="2">
    <GivenName>SWS JR</GivenName>
    <Surname>TESTCHD</Surname>
</PersonName>
```

Hope this helps!