# Sabre Web service error CHILD AGE DATA REQUIRED - USE *C2/C02-*C11

Tags: xml, sabre

I want to create a PNR for One Adult and One Child. As given below i passed passenger details to "PassengerDetailsRQ".

```
<PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2" version="3.2.0" IgnoreOnError="false" HaltOnError="false">
      <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false" RedisplayReservation="false" UnmaskCreditCard="true">
        <EndTransactionRQ>
          <EndTransaction Ind="true" />
          <Source ReceivedFrom="SWS" />
        </EndTransactionRQ>
      </PostProcessing>
      <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
        <AgencyInfo>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine>Address Address </AddressLine>
            <CityName>LONDON</CityName>
            <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            <PostalCode>55000</PostalCode>
            <StreetNmbr>I-2 JAVED</StreetNmbr>
            <VendorPrefs>
              <Airline Hosted="false" />
            </VendorPrefs>
          </Address>
          <Ticketing PseudoCityCode="XF18" QueueNumber="222" TicketTimeLimit="02-25T08:00" ShortText="TEST Short Text" TicketType="7TAW" />
        </AgencyInfo>
        <CustomerInfo>
          <ContactNumbers>
            <ContactNumber LocationCode="ISB" NameNumber="1.1" Phone="817-555-1212" PhoneUseType="H" />
          </ContactNumbers>
          <Email Address="yasirkhanmkd@yahoo.com" NameNumber="1.1" />
          <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="1.1" NameReference="ASD123" PassengerType="ADT">
            <GivenName>AMIR</GivenName>
            <Surname>KHAN</Surname>
          </PersonName>
          <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="2.1" NameReference="ASD123" PassengerType="C04">
            <GivenName>SALMAN</GivenName>
            <Surname>KHAN</Surname>
          </PersonName>
        </CustomerInfo>
      </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
    </PassengerDetailsRQ>
```

//Response

```
<PassengerDetailsRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2">
      <ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="Complete">
        <Success timeStamp="2016-02-17T09:16:15.982-06:00" />
        <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2016-02-17T09:16:15.981-06:00">
          <SystemSpecificResults>
            <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">CHILD AGE DATA REQUIRED - USE *C2/C02-*C11</Message>
          </SystemSpecificResults>
        </Warning>
      </ApplicationResults>
    </PassengerDetailsRS>
```

Why it Needs Child age? as i mention C04 in the request for child.?

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you just specify PassengerType="CNN" in your PersonName node?

Comment: i used PassengerType="CNN" also.. the same error exists.. as explained in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317560/looking-for-some-fields-in-travelitineraryreadrs) if we pass C04 then 04 is the age part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using ASD123 in NameReference parameter. The Issue was resolved by using the code like

```
<PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="2.1" NameReference="C04" PassengerType="CNN">
        <GivenName>SALMAN</GivenName>
        <Surname>KHAN</Surname>
      </PersonName>
```

Answer (score 1):

As a part of `PassengerDetailsRq` you may pass `SpecialReqDetails` in which you can put passenger details like documents, date of birth, etc.

More on it you'll find in Sabre documentation, below you have an example part of xml structure of `SpecialReqDetails` (in your xml it should be put just after 
`</PostProcessing>` tag and before `<TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>`)

```
<SpecialReqDetails>
  <SpecialServiceRQ>
    <SpecialServiceInfo>
      <AdvancePassenger>
        <PersonName DateOfBirth="2012-01-15" DocumentHolder="true" Gender="F" NameNumber="2.1">
           <GivenName>Sara</GivenName>
           <Surname>Smith</Surname>
        </PersonName>
      </AdvancePassenger>
    </SpecialServiceInfo>
  </SpecialServiceRQ>
</SpecialReqDetails>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this precious reply. I did accordingly as you told, But the issue still persist. My request is given below.. 
     `{<AdvancePassenger>
    <Document ExpirationDate="2018-05-05" Number="AS12345675" Type="P">
                <IssueCountry>PK</IssueCountry>
                <NationalityCountry>PK</NationalityCountry>
              </Document>
   <PersonName DateOfBirth="2012-01-15" Gender="M" NameNumber="2.1" DocumentHolder="true">
             <GivenName>Imran mstr</GivenName>
             <Surname>sam</Surname>
             </PersonName>
         </AdvancePassenger>}`

Comment: Still getting that Error:  
CHILD AGE DATA REQUIRED - USE *C2/C02-*C11 :(

Comment: the only thing I can recommend is to change C04 to CNN (PassengerType) for test purposes and see whether results are different. :(

Comment: I also used CNN but still it says CHILD AGE DATA REQUIRED - USE *C2/C02-*C11

Comment: sabre support told to use "SabreCommandLLSRQ" Web service, for example. 
`<SabreCommandLLSRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" EchoToken="String" TimeStamp="2016-02-25T07:29:43Z" Target="Production" Version="2003A.TsabreXML1.6.1" SequenceNmbr="1" PrimaryLangID="en-us" AltLangID="en-us">
      <Request CDATA="true" Output="SCREEN">
        <HostCommand>2.1¤*C04</HostCommand>
      </Request>
    </SabreCommandLLSRQ>`

Comment: I used the same but then it says CARRIER CODE REQUIRED USE  2/CARRIER CODE/FLT NBR/

Comment: basically each command operation should have its 'normal' xml equivalent (more convenient to use). unfortunately I've never had to call this command manually so I don't know why those errors appear. often Sabre errors are not verbose enough and without their support it's very difficult to figure out what is the reason causing transaction to fail

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you give a link for an old version of "PassengerDetailsRQ". I am using latest version. I may be due to version.

Comment: current is  http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/ServicesPlatform/PassengerDetailsRQ_v3.2.0_Design.xml


if you want access to the older one you have to change version number in url. for example http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/ServicesPlatform/PassengerDetailsRQ_v3.1.0_Design.xml leads to 3.1.0